# What is the right way to use new React hook useContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have some difficulties to understand the new way to use react Context API.
I have an app with a custom class Firebase. Now I want to make a hook to pass it. Before I used [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) *(higher-order Component)* and context.

My questions

1. Do I need to use HOC or it's a new way to do this?
2. Do I need the Context.Provider or it's new Hook?
3. Do I need to declare default value as a null or I can pass my Object
   right from context.js
4. How can I use a new Hook instead of HOC in mine code?

Here is my code with some comments related to questions

```
// context.js this is my hoc
// index.jsx
import App from './App'
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase'

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null)

export const withFirebase = Component => (props) => {
  // I don't need to wrap it to the FirebaseContext.Consumer
  // 1 But do I need this HOC or it's a new way?
  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext)
  return <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />
}

ReactDOM.render(
  // 2 Here I'm lost. Do I need the FirebaseContext.Provider or not?
  // 3 Do I need to declare value her or I should do it in context.js as a default?
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)

// App.jsx
// 4 Can I use a new Hook instead of HOC here and how?
import { withFirebase } from './components/Firebase/context'
const App = () => {
    const firebase = this.props.firebase // But should be useContext(FirebaseContext) or something like this?
    return(...)
}
export default withFirebase(App) // I don't need this with the Hook
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a tutorial website. I recommend setting up a new question for each of your questions. Make some attempt to solve the problem and if you get stuck we can help.

Comment: It looks like you want a beginners introduction to using the context hook, for which I would recommend Dave Ceddia's [https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/](https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/)

Comment: `useContext` is just an alternative to `Context.Consumer` or `myClass.contextType`. Use the variable and pass the context reference into it as default.

Comment: @JoshPittman I've seen this tutorial (and few more) but still have these questions. I think it's nice to put all together because I use context as I described (it works) and want to show where I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: @KenoClayton that's clear for me. but do I need to wrap the App to Provider?

Comment: You have misunderstood what stack overflow is for, please rephrase your question to address a specific reproducible problem that we can help you debug and solve. Help with a general understanding of how things work is not what stack is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should understand it first that, `useContext` is just to make use of Context and acts like a consumer and not Provider.

To answer your questions

> Do I need to use HOC or it's a new way to do this?

You don't need an HOC with hooks. Hooks are meant to replace HOCs and render props pattern.

> Do I need the Context.Provider or it's new Hook?

There is no hooks equivalent of Context.Provider. You have to use it as is.

> Do I need to declare default value as a null or I can pass my Object
>   right from context.js

The default value to createContext is only used if you don't pass a `value` props to the `Context.Provider`. If you pass it the default value is ignored.

> How can I use a new Hook instead of HOC in mine code?

Instead of using `useContext` in the component returned by HOC use it directly within the component

Sample code

```
/ context.js this is my hoc
// index.jsx
import App from './App'
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase'

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null)

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

**App.jsx**

```
const App = () => {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext) 
    return(...)
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you. That's work. One more thing. How to pass the default value? if I try Provider without it it's undefined.

Comment: `One more thing. How to pass the default value` if you don't pass the value prop to `FirebaseContext.Provider` you can specify the default value as argument to `React.createContext`

Comment: So I can just leave App without Provider and use the default value (Firebase is always the same)? Is it a good practice?

Comment: I tested and it works. Provider without the value prop will pass undefined. have a look it's in docs https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext `The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree.`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I got confused with something else. Thanks for informing

Comment: Hi @ShubhamKhatri I have a Context for Theme and almost every(50+) components are using Theme Context using HOC, what would you prefer in code, 50 line of code of `export default withTheme(MyComponent);` or `function MyComponent(){ const theme = useContext(ThemeContext); //...}`

Comment: @sanjeev As react docs state, you can write your existing components using hooks and avoid rewriting existing components. Using hocs and debugging them with react devtools is a little move overhead than hooks but otherwise there shouldn't be any issue keeping extra lines of code

Answer (score 0):

1. Do I need to use HOC or it's a new way to do this?

> No, you don't need to use HOC as best technique.
>
> Why?
> Starting from **React v7.0**, you can use functional-based components.
> From this version efficient is to use the the latest
> technique named HOOKS, which were designed to replace class and
> provide another great alternative to compose behavior into your
> components.

---

2. Do I need the Context.Provider or it's new Hook?

> Hook like useContext() has a relation with Context.Provider.
> **Context** is designed to share data that can be considered “global”.
>
> The **Provider** component accepts a
> value prop to be passed. Every Context come with a Provider.
>
> **Context.Provider** component available on the context instance is used to provide the context to its child components, no matter how deep they are.

---

3. Do I need to declare default value as a null or I can pass my Object right from context.js?

> No, you don't need necessarily to declare a default value.
>
> Example of defining the context in one corner of the codebase without defaultValue.
>
> const CountStateContext = React.createContext() // <-- define the context without defaultValue

---

4. How can I use a new Hook instead of HOC in mine code?

index.jsx

```
import App from './App'

import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase'

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null)

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Root Component: App.js, where will be used data comes form context:

```
const App = () => {
    const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext) 
    return(...)
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import About from './About'
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react'
import {colorThem} from '../App'

const listData =createContext()

const Home = () => {
    const [list , seTList]=useState([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
    const data = useContext(colorThem)
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>I'm From Home {data}</h1>
        <listData.Provider value={list}>
        <About/>
        </listData.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
export {listData}


 import { useContext } from "react"
 import { listData } from "./Home"

const About = () => {
const arr = useContext(listData)
 console.log(arr)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About components </h1>
    {
        arr.map((item ,index)=><h1 key={index}>{item}</h1>)
    }
    </div>
  )
}

export default About
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested code for useContext, In this example I am updating the form data and rendering the form data in different component.

```js
import React, {createContext, useReducer, useContext} from 'react';

// CREATING THE CONTEXT
const userContext = createContext(null);

// REDUCER FUNCTION FOR UPDATING THE CONTEXT
const reducerFn = (state = [], payload) => {
    switch (payload.type) {
        case 'FIRST_NAME':
            return {...state, formData: {firstName: payload.payload, lastName: state.formData.lastName}}
        case 'LAST_NAME':
            return {...state, formData: {firstName: state.formData.firstName, lastName: payload.payload}}
    
        default:
            return {...state};
    }
}

// CONTEXT PROVIDER COMPONENT TO PASS THE CONTEXT VALUE 
const AppContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducerFn, {formData: {firstName: '', lastName: ''}});
    return(
        <userContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
            {children}
        </userContext.Provider>
    )
}

// ACTION CREATION 
const updateFname = (val) => {
    return {
        type: 'FIRST_NAME',
        payload: val
    }
}

const updateLname = (val) => {
    return {
        type: 'LAST_NAME',
        payload: val
    }
}
// ACTION CREATION 



// FORM COMPONENT AND UPDATING THE FORMDATA USING CONTEXT
const UserForm = () => {
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(userContext)
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='fname'>First Name</label>
                <input type='text' id='fname' onChange={(e) => dispatch(updateFname(e.target.value))}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor='lname'>Last Name</label>
                <input type='text' id='lname' onChange={(e) => dispatch(updateLname(e.target.value))}/>
            </div>
            
        </>
    )
}

// COMPONENT FOR DISPLAYING THE FORMDATA
const DisplayFormData = () => {
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(userContext);
    return(
        <div>
            <p>First Name is : {state.formData.firstName} and last Name is {state.formData.lastName}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

// MAIN COMPONENT
function Question3Context(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <AppContextProvider>
                <UserForm />
                <DisplayFormData />
            </AppContextProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Question3Context;
```